# Правила написания нечленораздельных звуков

Tags: орфография, лексика, слитно-дефис

Существуют ли правила изображения на письме нечленораздельных звуков и звукоподражаний?

Допустим:
визг — **Иииии!** или **И-и-и-и!**
мычание — **Муууу!** или **Му-у-у!**

Вопрос не праздный, потому что есть и устойчивые формы.
Допустим, мы всегда пишем "тук-тук" через дефис.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Звукоподражательные слова — это особая группа слов, передающих различные звуки, издаваемые человеком и животными, а также звуки, которые существуют в живой и неживой природе.
По внешнему виду, морфологическим и синтаксическим особенностям звукоподражательные слова близки к междометиям, но отличаются от них тем, что не передают ни чувств, ни волеизъявлений.
В текстах художественных произведений они используются как экспрессивно-стилистическое средство отображения действительности:

*Каждый удар сердца болью отдавался в груди – тук, тук, тук – остановка – и снова тук, тук, тук... Если только она вернется.

Мари лежала и прислушивалась к биению.

Тук. Тук. Тук... Тишина... Тук. Тук. Тук... Тишина... Тук. Тук. Тук...

А вдруг оно прямо сейчас остановится совсем?

Ну вот!

Снова тишина!*
[**Р. Брэдбери. Следующий**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=M9zW7NR9SXgC&pg=PT39&lpg=PT39&dq=%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BA...%20%D0%98%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA...&source=bl&ots=cX8F9k1zWn&sig=7ijyiLHNLVgHPv5G-Kxvg7cYNAs&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ8oK-ob7ZAhXEYlAKHQZMCKcQ6AEIODAG#v=onepage&q=%D0%A2%D1%83%D0%BA...%20%D0%98%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA...&f=false)

Большая часть звукоподражаний представляет собой непроизводные слова:
**хрю, мяу, гав, тук, апчхи**...
Производные лексемы образуются путем повтора одних и тех же или близких звуковых комплексов. Сложные звукоподражательные слова обычно пишутся через дефис:
**гав-гав, тик-так, ку-ку, куд-кудах, динь-динь-динь, пиф-паф, чик-чирик**...
[**Звукоподражания**](http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/zvukopodrajaniya-70866.html)
[**Звукоподражательные слова**](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200800610)

У разных авторов может быть разное оформление таких словечек:

*Я петух, будильник ночи,

С крику выбился из мочи,

И принёс на Стикс-реку

Я своё **кукареку**.*
В. Жуковский

*...Шевельнется, встрепенется,

К той сторонке обернется

И кричит: „**Кири-ку-ку**.

Царствуй, лежа на боку!“*
А. С. Пушкин

*Петя-петушок... крыльями замахал, во все горло заорал: «**Ку-ка-ре-ку**!»*
К. Ушинский

*Зрители, потупив очи, разбрелись кто куда. Через полминуты из мастерской донеслось дружное пение: «Ма-му-ми-мууууу».*
А. Дышев. Женат на собственной смерти

*— Что ты несёшь? Какой вой?

— Вот такой, – и она, задрав голову, тоненько и протяжно завыла. – У-у-у!.. Ау-ау-ооо!!!*
С. Десницкий. Пётр и Павел. 1957 год

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (после комментария)
*И всё-таки мне придётся обратиться к конкретному случаю.*

Из черновика:
**И в этот самый момент пол снова дрогнул. Откуда-то снизу пронёсся поток горячего воздуха, и во тьму подземелья ворвался тот же грохочущий, надрывающий душу и уши, звук.

- Тащиии!! Ииииии !!! – истошный визг старого Свиндле пронзил этот грохот, как раскалённая игла пронзает масло.**

1. Запятая после "воздуха" перед "и" не нужна: общее для двух частей предложения — "откуда-то снизу".
2. *Ворвался* и *надрывающий* — однокоренные слова (корни -рв-/-рыв-).
   Первый абзац (для передачи особенностей звука) я бы закончила так:
   ...грохочущий звук, терзающий и мозг, и душу.
   (Грохо**чущ**ий, надрываю**щ**ий ду**ш**у и у**ш**и — слишком много "ч-щ-ш-ш", текст не воспринимается.)
3. Если хочется использовать и визгливое "тащи", и долгое "и", то лучше их разделить.
4. *Пронзил* и *пронзает* в одном предложении — это задумка такая?

Получилось:
**Откуда-то снизу пронёсся поток горячего воздуха и во тьму подземелья ворвался тот же грохочущий звук, терзающий и мозг, и душу.

— Тащи-и-и-и! — истошный визг старого Свиндле пронзил этот грохот, как раскалённая игла пронзает масло. Эхом разлетелось: — И-и! И-и!**

P.S. Получилось два вопроса — в одном; объем ответа — громадный, разнотемный, нечитабельный. На будущее: Вам нужно было сразу в вопросе предоставить этот текст, а то рассматриваем тут абстрактные "му" да "кукареку" с вариациями. Вопрос должен быть четким и конкретным.

Comment: Спасибо! И всё-таки мне придётся обратиться к конкретному случаю. Ничего не поделаешь. Я понимаю, что авторское право здесь превалирует, но речь идёт об удобочитаемости. Конкретный пример из черновика: "И в этот самый момент пол снова дрогнул. 
Откуда-то снизу пронёсся поток горячего воздуха, и во тьму подземелья ворвался тот же грохочущий, надрывающий душу и уши, звук. 
- Тащиии!! Ииииии !!! – истошный визг старого Свиндле пронзил этот грохот, как раскалённая игла пронзает масло."

Comment: И ещё - какой вариант выглядит экспрессивнее, на ваш взгляд?